group by with counted/sum data from two different tables
I have the following tables:
contacts



agent_name




John


John


Sally



refusals



agent_name
reason




John
Dropped


Sally
NoAnswer



I want a query that will show me this:



agent_name
countofcontacts
countofrefusals




John
2
1


Sally
1
1



SELECT
CallData.Agent_Name
,count(*) as RefusalCount
--,count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() as Percentage
,sum(count(*)) over() as TotalCount
FROM disposition as CallData
left outer join refusals as refusals on CallData.Contact_ID = refusals.contact_id
where 
  parse_timestamp("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", refuse_time) > '2024-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
  AND refusals.Reason in ('NoAnswer','Dropped')
  AND users.Status = 'Active'
group by CallData.Agent_Name
order by RefusalCount desc

This gives me the correct count for refusals but the "TotalCount" is wrong.

Hi - your SQL references a table called “disposition” but this doesn’t exist in the sample data you’ve provided. When you join contacts to refusals, how do you know which “John” in contacts is the “John” in refusals?

UNION ALL the tables. GROUP BY the result:
select agent_name, count(c) as countofcontacts, count(r) as countofrefusals
from
  (select agent_name, 'c' as c, null as r from contacts
   union all
   select agent_name, null, 'r' from refusals
  ) dt
group by agent_name
order by agent_name

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/ErlNtL-R

Actually, I had a follow up. If I want to group by a column that's only in the contacts table, how can I do that?

@user24929248 If you have another question, create a new question, don't misuse comments for that.
